# NestJS - Controller - Get(':id') returned 404

Tags: routes, controller, nestjs, url-parameters

I have the following code in my orders.controller.ts file:

```
@Controller('orders')
export class OrdersController {
  constructor(private ordersService: OrdersService) {}

  @Get(':id')
  async getOrderById(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Promise<Order> {
    return this.ordersService.getOrderById(id);
  }
}
```

I want to test the Get(':id') route with the following url: http://localhost:3000/orders?id=1

but I still have a 404 error:

```
{
     "statusCode": 404,
     "message": "Cannot GET /orders?id=1",
     "error": "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: It should be @Controller(/orders) and @Get(/:id)

Comment: @CharchitKapoor your solution is not working

Comment: Sorry my bad, your request url should be /orders/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to handle `GET /orders?id=1`:

```js
@Controller('orders')
export class OrdersController {
  constructor(private ordersService: OrdersService) {}

  @Get()
  async getOrderById(@Query('id') id?: string): Promise<Order> {
    return this.ordersService.getOrderById(id);
  }
}
```

otherwise you should make a `GET /orders/1` request.